# Best way to merge and remove duplicates from multiple lists in Java

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, list, merge

I have a situation where I will be receiving 2+ `ArrayList<Widget>` and I need to be able to merge all the lists and remove any duplicate `Widget` so that I wind up with only 1 `ArrayList<Widget>` that contains all `Widget`s from all the merged lists, but without any duplicates.

Assume `Widget` has an overridden `equals` method that *can* be used for determining whether two `Widget`s are duplicates, although there may be a better way:

```
public ArrayList<Widget> mergeAndRemoveDupes(ArrayList<Widget> widgets...) {
    // ???
}
```

Looking for the most algorithmically efficient way of accomplishing this. I am happy to use Apache Commons or any other open source libs that would help me out too! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For each `ArrayList<Widget>`, add each element to a `Set<Widget>` (`HashSet` or `TreeSet`, depending on whether they can be ordered in some way, or are hashable) utilizing `addAll`. Sets contain no duplicates by default.

You can convert this `Set` back into an `(Array)List` if you need to at the end.

Note you will need to implement `hashCode` for your `Widget` class if you decide to use a `HashSet`, but if you have an overridden `equals,` you should do this anyway.

Edit: Here's an example:

```
//Either the class itself needs to implement Comparable<T>, or a similar
//Comparable instance needs to be passed into a TreeSet 
public class Widget implements Comparable<Widget>
{
    private final String name;
    private final int id;

    Widget(String n, int i)
    {
        name = n;
        id = i;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    //Something like this already exists in your class
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if(o != null && (o instanceof Widget)) {
            return ((Widget)o).getName().equals(name) &&
                   ((Widget)o).getId() == id;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //This is required for HashSet
    //Note that if you override equals, you should override this
    //as well. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java
    @Override 
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return ((Integer)id).hashCode() + name.hashCode();
    }

    //This is required for TreeSet
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Widget w)
    {
        if(id < w.getId()) return -1;
        else if(id > w.getId()) return 1;
        return name.compareTo(w.getName());
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Widget: " + name + ", id: " + id;
    }
}
```

If you want to use a `TreeSet` but don't want to implement `Comparable<T>` on your `Widget` class, you can give the set itself a `Comparator` object:

```
private Set<Widget> treeSet;
....
treeSet = new TreeSet<Widget>(new Comparator<Widget>() {
            public int compare(Widget w1, Widget w2)
            {
                if(w1.getId() < w2.getId()) return -1;
                else if(w1.getId() > w2.getId()) return 1;
                return w1.getName().compareTo(w2.getName());
            }
           });
```

Comment: Wow thanks @Yuushi (+1) - will I get a runtime exception if I try to add a dupe to the set? Or will Java just ignore the added dupe (which is what I want). Thanks again!

Comment: Java will just ignore the added duplicate

Comment: @IAmYourFaja It will simply ignore the dupe.

Comment: Assuming that each list is already mathematically a set,  it would be faster to use Set.addAll instead of aging one element at a time.

Comment: Chris, addAll takes a collection, not only a set. Therefore any List is also a valid candidate for [addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) provided its containing class responds to hashCode

Comment: Last followup @Yuushi (+1 again) - remember, these individual lists are actually coming from totally separate sources before they get passed to the `mergeAndRemoveDupes` method. So I *need* to use `equals()` (or something similar) to guarantee dupes don't wind up in the final (merged) list. So I ask: how does `Set` know to ignore dupes? `equals()`? Something else? Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja `HashSet` uses `hashCode` - two things that hash to the same value are considered equal. `TreeSet` uses a comparator - thus expecting your class to be of the form `Widget implements Comparable<Widget>`, or when you construct the `TreeSet`, to pass in a  Comparator (for example, `TreeSet(new Comparable<Widget>(...))`

Comment: @IAmYourFaja I've added an example of what you (may) need to add to your `Widget` class to allow addition into a `Set`.

Comment: @Yuushi  Two items with the same hash code are considered *possibly equal*. Set will still call equals after a hash match to check if the items are actually the same!

Comment: @ChrisPitman Thanks...I've been in C++ land for too long, I haven't touched Java for a while, so I'm forgetting some of the intricacies.

Comment: can this affect performence in case we are dealing with thousands of objects ?

Answer (score 9):

I would do it this way

```
Set<Widget> set = new HashSet<>(list1);
set.addAll(list2);
List<Widget> mergeList = new ArrayList<>(set);
```

Comment: Thanks @Evgeniy (+1) - please see my last question to Yuushi in his/her answer above - I have the same question for you!

Comment: Since we are using Set duplicates will not be added. There will be no exceptions

Answer (score 2):

Use `Set` Collection Class,

```
ArrayList<Widget> mergeList = new ArrayList<widget>();
mergeList.addAll(widgets1);
mergeList.addAll(widgets2);
Set<Widget> set  = new HashSet<Widget>(mergeList);
ArrayList<Widget> mergeListWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<widget>();
mergeListWithoutDuplicates .addAll(set);
return mergeListWithoutDuplicates;
```

Now here Set will remove all duplicates values from your ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks @buptcoder (+1) - please see my last question to Yuushi in his/her answer above - I have the same question for you!